# How can I move game object from one side to the other side of the screen in a set time?

Tags: android, coordinates

Lets assume I want to make an android game with a simple object on the screen. The object starts with x = 0, and ends at x = right side of screen.

Lets also assume we live in a perfect world and every device runs at exactly 30 FPS. I could certainly use the below code snippet to get from point "0" to "right side of the screen" but it will most definitely take a variable amount of time on every device due to fragmentation.

```
while(x < rightSideOfScreen)
 x++;
```

The only coordinate system I know of is android.graphics.Point, which is what I am currently using in my game.

1. Is there a better way to manage 2D game coordinates?
2. How could I make the simple game object reach from point "0" to point "right side of screen" in the same amount of time on all devices?

Comment: You need to remember the timestamp of starting point, then in every `onDraw` calculate x coordinate depending on current time and view width. On my devices, for example, onDraw is called every 12-20 ms, more correlated to 60fps, not 30

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on your requirements. If your game consist of this one object moving from left to right in constant time then that is probably all you need. If you are doing a 3d FPS shoot-em-up you might want to look into [matrices](http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/basic-3d-math-matrices) and [quaternions](http://content.gpwiki.org/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation) etc. In the middle there are engines and libraries that can help you, such as [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).
2. Here is some code (NOT tested):

[...]

```
long animationStartTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
final long CONSTANT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_TIME = 10*1000;//10 seconds in millis

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final int w=canvas.getWidth();
    final long timePassed=now-animationStartTime;
    final int x=(timePassed*w)/CONSTANT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT_TIME; // Calculate position deterministically based on time since animation start
    canvas.drawBitmap(myObjectBitmap, x , 100, null);
    //Just for fun, loop the animation
    if(x>w){
        animationStartTime=now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interpolation I guess:

```
targetX = rightSideOfScreen;


x += (targetX - x) * 0.08f * delta * FPS;
```

Play around with the 0.08f value

The "perfect world" you are talking about is used in my example above. By multiplying movement with the delta passed in the render() methods, you ensure it runs the same on all devices.